# How to use django.contrib.auth with django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, angularjs, authentication, django-rest-framework

`django-rest-framework` makes use of `django.contrib.auth` for authentication and authorization (as stated in the [django-rest-framework authentication api guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication))

However, no-where in the documentation does it talk about how users are actually authenticated using the rest-framework

By default the `django.contrib.auth` views will respond with a server-side rendered login form.

However, if using a client-side framework such as AngularJs this is not desired - you simply want an api endpoint against which you can authenticate.

**Questions:**

- Is there `django-rest-framework` documentation I am somehow missing which explains how user authentication is done-out-of-the-box?
- Does an out-of-the-box solution even exist?
- If not, what is the recommended way of achieving this with minimal reinvention of the wheel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

lets say that you have login view:

Note: with this method you have to assure SSL/TLS because username and password are sending as plain text.

```
import json
import requests

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        login_url = 'http://your_url:port/rest-api/login/'
        response = requests.post(login_url, data={'username': username, 'password': password})
        response = json.loads(response.text)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return render_to_response("login.html", {"success": True}, RequestContext(request))
```

your view in rest-api:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend as DjangoModelBackend

def login(request):
    response = base_response.copy()
    username = request.DATA.get('username', '')
    password = request.DATA.get('password', '')

    user = DjangoModelBackend().authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        response["message"] = "Authenticated"
    else:
        response["message"] = "Login Failed"

    return Response(response)
```

and here is the part of ModelBackend

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ModelBackend(object):

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually go through login forms when authenticating yourself at an API endpoint - you either use an API token or send the authentication credentials through a header, see [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax) on how to do that.